# .htaccess file - Redirecting/Masking to hidden directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have the below code that we add into the root of a domain name that masks the directory of wordpress to try and keep it hidden. I would rather not have to specify the domain name in the .htaccess file so I can just upload the same file to all the sites. Can someone help suggest how I can alter this to make it work with any domain?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress-hidden/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress-hidden/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainname.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress-hidden/index.php [L]
```

Comment: If you add this at the root of a specific domain, then why is this including _any_ checks for the host name to begin with? What purpose are they supposed to serve in that scenario?

Comment: I really have no clue as I am not good with htaccess files. It was just code I found on the internet many years ago and just continue to use it. So I could just delete those two lines that have the domain and it will work the same? I am just not where I can test it right now.